# Get numbers and characters after 3 expression with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a regular expression to get the next value of a particular word in some huge text.

Example:

```
Money:   0,00    0,00    0,00   50,00
```

Currently I'm taking the value of 0.00 with the following Regex:

```
        var obj     =
        var text    = 'HUGE TEXT HERE'
        var reg     = new RegExp('Money' + '.*?(\\d\\S*)');
        var match   = reg.exec(text);

        if (match === null) {
            obj[key] = '';
            continue;
        }

        obj[key] = match[1];
```

output:

```
object.money = '0,00'
```

This value is dynamic and sometimes the word 'Money' changes. So i need to be able to pass the word name.
    
I would like to amplify my regular expression to ignore the next three expressions and then get the value. It is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just match the numbers? Seems like there is no need to match the text.

Comment: You could capture the text in its own capture group, then verify that it's what you expect. But that doesn't really clean up your regex, it just means "MONEY$" will work and not treat the $ as the end of the string.

Comment: i need pass the word @DavidEhrmann

Comment: it is impossible ignore the next 3 values?

Comment: So `new Reg Exp(myVariable  + '.*?(\\d\\S*)')`

Comment: + + doesn't work @epascarello, could you be more specifically?

Comment: Dynamic work can be targeted using a simple \w, nor I don't understand the will..

Comment: Nico, can you post as a answer?

Comment: @AmandaFerrari Instead of putting the word in the regex, you could look for any word, then if the regex matches, check that the word you found is the word you're looking for.

Comment: i need explicity pass the word in my case @DavidEhrmann

Comment: @AmandaFerrari Why can't you check it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look for (and ignore) the three repeating numbers, then catch the last one:

```
(?:\d\S*\s+){3}(\d\S*)
```

Where:

```
(?:...)
```

means "don't include this group in the returned list of captured groups" and

```
{3}
```

means "match three of them".

We're including `\s+` at the end to catch the whitespace between the numbers.

Something like (simplified):

```js
var obj = {};
var key = 'Money';
var text = "Something something:\n" +
    "Money: 1,00 2,00 3,00 3,00\n" +
    "Something else";
var reg = new RegExp(key + '\\b.*?(?:\\d\\S*\\s+){3}(\\d\\S*)');
var match = reg.exec(text);

if (match === null)
  obj[key] = '';
else
  obj[key] = match[1];

console.log(obj[key]);
```

Comment: If is not ask to much, could you explain? <3

Comment: Added some additional explanation.